# How to avoid leaking my url parameters with rest template ResourceAccessException exception?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a partner that may be offline for a couple of seconds and we want to log the failed attempt.

Then, I have a simple call:

```
restTemplate.getForObject("https://myurl/{param}", Response.class, paramValue);
```

The issue is that if something wrong happens, the completely `URL` will be logged in the exception, example:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://myurl/paramValue".
```

My question is how can I avoid the param value to be available in the exception message because it can be potentially leaking important data.

Of course, I can always manually handle the exception but I did not want to lose the stack trace. In my understanding, it should have a away to configure the `RestTemplate` handler to do not log the expanded URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch exception and throw new exception with changed message and everything else the same (including stacktrace) as caught one.

```
try {
  someObject.someMethod();
} catch (ResourceAccessException oldEx) {
  newEx = new ResourceAccessException("newMessage", oldEx.getCause(), true, true);
  newEx.setStacTrace(oldEx.getStackTrace());
  throw newEx;
}
```